Geiser: Cannot find guile implementation
Emacs version: 29.4
Guile version: 3.0.10
OS: Arch Linux
I have installed guile through pacman. which guile returns /usr/bin/guile. I began with this in my init.el:
(use-package geiser
  :init
  (setq geiser-active-implementations '(guile)
        geiser-scheme-implementation '(guile)))

I can verify that these have set properly with C-h v. However, whenever I try to run geiser, I get the Cannot find guile implementation error. After some searching around, I found suggestions to set either geiser-guile-load-path or geiser-guile-binary, but these are not documented as variables and setting either of them to /usr/bin/guile has no effect.
If I add use-package geiser-guile to my init.el, trying to run geiser instead returns:
Unable to start REPL:
Wrong type argument: stringp, 47


The value of geiser-scheme-implementation has to be a symbol, not a list: C-h v geiser-scheme-implementation says:
geiser-scheme-implementation is a variable defined in ‘geiser-impl.el’.

Its value is nil

The Scheme implementation to be used by Geiser.

  Automatically becomes buffer-local when set.
  This variable is safe as a file local variable if its value
  satisfies the predicate ‘symbolp’.

So try:
(setq geiser-scheme-implementation 'guile)

but of course this may not be the only thing that is wrong.
And BTW, if its value is nil, I believe that geiser will prompt you for the implementation.
